export not working
The map is 12000*12000 pixels, and the four corners of the map are created at 122.921°E~156.890°E and 20.413°N~54.382°N.
I added a new projection to it +proj=eqc +lat_ts=35.025 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=135.762 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
When I set the extent without the new projection I can set it using the coordinates however when I set to the new projection the numbers are much larger. Setting the output width and height also changes the extent. Also how do I decide what dpi and scale do I use?

This should be an edit to your previous Question. How to export a map as image with a specific extent but I suggest you leave out the DPI/scale "Also", because we're a One question per Question site, as described in the Tour.
